# Can I have more than one AJAX request at the same time?

Tags: html, ajax

Something tells me this is trivial, but better safe than buggy.

If I have an ongoing AJAX request, say request A (and server is still to send response), then I fire another request to the same AJAX performing call B, do each of these responses come back normally, or does the XMLHttpRequest object only takes care of one at a time (where it either ignores the first request (A) once the second becomes the 'active' request?

Or does it ignores the second (B) because the XMLHttpRequest object is already 'busy' with A)?

I already have an "array of requests" plan, where I queue requests, and once the callback is triggered, it scans that array for further waiting requests if needed, but I am not sure I need this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AJAX is a generic acronym meaning 'asynchronous javascript'. It means that you can run any number of AJAX requests concurrently. Any modern javascript framework should handle multiple concurrent requests correctly.

Comment: Thank you! That's the best news I heard since I started this project I'm working on :)